# Can not get customer profile id from Authorize.net

Tags: customer-account, authorize.net

I have an issue with not getting authorize.net customer profile id.
Below is my code using which I am requesting for 'CreateCustomerProfile.'

```
$this->getRequest()
            ->reset()
            ->setData(array(
                           'merchantAuthentication' => array(
                               'name' => trim($this->getApiLoginId()),
                               'transactionKey' => trim($this->getTransactionKey())
                           ),
                           'profile' => array(
                               'merchantCustomerId' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getCustomerId(),
                               'description' =>  $this->storeUrl(),
                               'email' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getCustomerEmail(),
                               'paymentProfiles' => array(
                                   'CustomerPaymentProfileType' => array(
                                       'customerType' => 'individual',
                                       'billTo' => array(
                                           'firstName' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname(),
                                           'lastName' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getLastname(),
                                           'address' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getStreet(-1),
                                           'state' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getRegion(),
                                           'city' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getCity(),
                                           'company' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getCompany(),
                                           'country' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getCountry(),
                                           'zip' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode(),
                                           'phoneNumber' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone(),
                                           'faxNumber' => $this->getPayment()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getFax(),
                                       ),
                                       'payment' => $this->_convertPayment($this->getPayment())
                                   )
                               )
                           ),
                           'validationMode' => 'liveMode'
                      ));
```

Now issue is,some times I get Customer profile id and some time not.So by analyze this code,. please help me why this issue is generated.